Switching location satellite system on Android 14 (Samsung S23+)
Is it possible to force localization through a specific satellite system in case of jamming/bad reception.
I see on GPS test that my phone (S23+, Android 14) can receive Glonass/Galileo/Beidou
But I did not manage to base navigation on one of them (Maps or other).
I will be happy to find a solution, preferably with offline maps, in order to minimize external data dependency.

I don't think it's possible and it wouldn't matter anyway.

I have tried this myself, but was unable to find a way to do it on Android.
The problem with poor reception is to do with clouds and building obstructions around you, in particular spots. It can also be where you phone is in the car, the quality of the antenna in the phone etc.
For any of those reasons, a different satellite system is not going to improve things.

Hello,thank you, I am speaking in case of jamming.
And in general, how to switch localization from default (GPS) to a chosen one (GPS/GLONASS/Beidou/Galileo...)
